# Unset in foreach loop turns array into associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json, unset

I use the following code to conditionally remove items from an array:

```
$fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana', 'pineapple'];

echo json_encode($fruits) ."<br>";

foreach ($fruits as $key=>$fruit) {
    if (in_array($fruit, ['apple', 'orange', 'melon', 'banana'])) {
        unset($fruits[$key]);
    }
}

echo json_encode($fruits) ."<br>";
```

Now the problem is that the unset changes the array to an associative array. How should I remove items without causing this?

Output:

```
["apple","orange","melon","banana","pineapple"]
{"4":"pineapple"}
```

Comment: I don't think anything changed, you just created a hole in your array and so the display function now explicitly prints out the index since some are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that whenever `json_encode` finds an array which does not have consecutive numeric keys starting at 0, it has to represent it as an object with numeric keys to get an accurate representation of the array in JavaScript (see Example #4 on the [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode)). You can work around this by running the array through `array_values` to re-index it to 0. For example:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "\n";
unset($array[1]);
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "\n";
$array = array_values($array);
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
[
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
]
{
    "0": "a",
    "2": "c"
}
[
    "a",
    "c"
]
```

In your case, after the `foreach` loop, you would use

```
$fruits = array_values($fruits);
```

to reset the indexes in that array.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2PneY)